# How to serialize a nested dataset with ASP.NET and Json.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, json.net

Currently I am using [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize a dataset to json.

**VB.NET**

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Sub GetData()
  Dim json As String

  Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Con").ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("sp", con)
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure    
      Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Using ds As New DataSet()
          sda.Fill(ds)
          json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented)    
        End Using
      End Using    
    End Using
  End Using

  Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  Context.Response.Write(json)
End Sub
```

**JSON** (Output)

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "Name": "Head1",
      "Number": 0
    },
    {
      "Name": "Head1",
      "Number": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "Head2",
      "Number": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Desired output

I have created a seperate stored procedure to populate the nested data and am trying to work out how to iterate through the rows of the dataset/json and insert the nested data into each item.

In .net I would simply do a `for each` item loop.

**JSON**

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "Name": "Head1"
      "NumberSection": [
        "Number": 0,
        "Number": 1
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Head2"
      "NumberSection": [
        "Number": 0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Suggestions can be in `C#` or `VB`

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935102/how-to-create-nested-xml-from-datatable-or-dataset-without-looping json / xml shouldn't matter.

Comment: @djv thanks I will look into this.